# Find and merging duplicate data. Make it a column name followed by its data respectively

Tags: excel, vba

Im a student and I need a help. I have a repeated text data from column x, and I want it to become a header then its table content from data in the column y respectively match by data column x. Im currently using an excel and you guys may recommend what else easier tools that I can use.

So basically i want to make a table from the left table to be like the right table

[image]

Comment: Try placing the two columns in an array, then use a dictionary. The A:A unique values will be its keys and each occurrence will be kept in the dictionary item. Finally load a final array processing the dictionary in discussion.

Comment: You received two answers... Didn't you find some time to test them? It is, at least, polite to do that and send some feedback, since somebody spent some time to solve your problem.

Comment: The etiquette of Stackoverflow is to present the question and the code you used to attempt to solve the problem. That was probably the reason for the downvote.

Comment: This is easy with Power Query just with three steps it can be accompished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next VBA code. It uses a Scripting `Dictionary` loaded with `column x` as keys and `column y` as items. Using arrays and the mentioned dictionary, it mostly works in memory and should be very fast:

```
Sub UniqueDataValues()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, maxCol As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet  'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  'load the dictionary:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
       dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2)
  Next i

  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To UBound(arr))
  Dim k As Long, key, arrIt
  k = 1
  For Each key In dict.Keys
     arrIt = Split(dict(key), "|")
     If UBound(arrIt) + 1 > maxCol Then maxCol = UBound(arrIt) + 1
     arrFin(k, 1) = key
     For i = 1 To UBound(arrIt)
           arrFin(k, 1 + i) = arrIt(i)
     Next i
     k = k + 1
  Next key
  
  'drop the final array content at once:
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To k - 1)
  With sh.Range("J2").Resize(dict.count, k - 1)
    .Value2 = Application.Transpose(arrFin)
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: woaah, this script really works, thank you, really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are stored in column A and B, try this formula:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/($A:$A=E$1),ROW(E2)-ROW($E$2)+1))
```

Comment: i aprreciates your help, after i tried this formula then, excel said "there is a problem with this formula', i tried to figure it out but i still cant find the solution

Comment: Ye, sorry. A closing bracket was missing. Also i forgot to put it in an index formula since it would return just the index of the searched cell (the fake data misled me).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just converting to pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

### Transform Data (*Attributes* and *Values* Only)

- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransformData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    ' s - Source (read from)
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstRowAddress As String = "X2:Y2" ' at least two columns!
    Const saColumn As Long = 1 ' Attributes (Unique) Column
    Const svColumn As Long = 2 ' Values Column
    ' d - Destination (write to)
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "AB2"
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg') and write its number of rows
    ' to a variable ('srCount').
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    ' Reference the first row of the source (columns) range.
    With sws.Range(sFirstRowAddress)
        ' Attempt to reference the bottom-most non-empty cell
        ' in the columns range ('.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)'),
        ' e.g. for 'sFirstRowAddress = "A2:B2"' this means 'A2:B1048576'.
        Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The columns range is empty."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        srCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the source columns to 2D one-based one-column
    ' arrays, the source arrays ('saData', 'svData'), .
    Dim saData() As Variant
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim saData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): saData(1, 1) = srg.Columns(saColumn).Value
        ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData(1, 1) = srg.Columns(svColumn).Value
    Else
        saData = srg.Columns(saColumn).Value
        svData = srg.Columns(svColumn).Value
    End If
    
    ' Create and reference a dictionary object,
    ' the source dictionary ('sDict').
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    ' Each 'key' in the source dictionary will hold a unique value
    ' from the attributes column ('saColumn'),
    ' while the associated 'item' ('sDict(sKey)') will hold
    ' a collection holding the values from the values column ('svColumn').
    Dim sKey As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sKey = saData(sr, 1)
        If Not sDict.Exists(sKey) Then ' the 'key' doesn't exist
            Set sDict(sKey) = New Collection
        'Else ' the 'key' exists i.e. the 'item' already holds a collection
        End If
        ' Write the current value to the collection.
        sDict(sKey).Add svData(sr, 1)
    Next sr
    Erase saData ' release memory; the data is in the source dictionary
    Erase svData ' release memory; the data is in the source dictionary
    
    ' Determine the destination rows count ('drCount').
    Dim drCount As Long
    For Each sKey In sDict.Keys
        If sDict(sKey).Count > drCount Then
            drCount = sDict(sKey).Count
        End If
    Next
    drCount = drCount + 1 ' 1 for the headers
    
    ' The the destination columns count ('dcCount') is equal
    ' to the source dictionary's count.
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = sDict.Count
    
    ' Define the destination array ('dData'), a 2D one-based array.
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim sItem As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    ' Looping through the 'keys' ('sKey') of the source dictionary ('sDict')
    ' also means looping through the associated 'items' ('sDict(sKey)').
    ' It also means looping through the columns ('dc')
    ' of the destination array ('dData').
    For Each sKey In sDict.Keys
        ' Write header.
        dc = dc + 1 ' next column
        dData(1, dc) = sKey ' write
        ' Write data.
        ' Looping through the 'items' ('sItem') of the collection held
        ' in the 'item' ('sDict(Key)') of the source dictionary ('sDict')
        ' also means looping through the rows ('dr')
        ' of the destination array ('dData').
        dr = 1 ' skip the first row containing headers
        For Each sItem In sDict(sKey)
            dr = dr + 1 ' next row
            dData(dr, dc) = sItem ' write
        Next sItem
    Next sKey
    Set sDict = Nothing ' release memory; the data is in the destination array
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    ' Reference the destination first cell ('dfCell').
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
    
    ' Reference the destination range ('drg').
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    ' Clear the destination columns range
    ' e.g. for 'dFirstCellAddress = "A1"' this means 'A1:XFD1048576'.
    dfCell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row + 1, _
        dws.Columns.Count - dfCell.Column + 1).Clear
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    drg.Value = dData
    Erase dData ' release memory; the data is in the destination range
    
    ' Format the destination range.
    With drg
        ' Format the header row.
        With .Rows(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        ' Format the data rows.
        With .Resize(drCount - 1).Offset(1)
        
        End With
        ' Format all rows.
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    'wb.Save
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data transformed.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: i aprreciates your help, after i run this script on vba it said "the columns range are empty",  im new in this vba learning, and i cant understand why this didnt worked out.